# Ember.js closing child view from controller actions

Tags: ember.js

I create a crud app using Ember.js where for delete there is no template/child view, just clicking the X button in parent view

[image]

the problem is when I click the title for view/update (the child view is active) and then directly after that deleting the corresponding model of the view/update in the parent view using the X, the child view (view/update) is not closing or deactivating.

[image]

as you can see the view/update child view for model posts a-a-a is still open even though the model is already deleted.

I solve this by creating an empty child view for delete and do the

```
this.transitionToRoute('delete');
```

to overwrite and clearing the view/update child view. **I think this is more like a hack than a proper solution.**. Is there a way to close the view/update child view from the delete controller actions?

Comment: It doesn't matter how the situation occurs-  If you delete a model on a route that is represented by a particular URL and you don't transition to a different route, you will be left on an route with a model that does not exist on the server.  You have to decide what it means when the user takes this action and what is the best thing to do when that happens.

Comment: so, you mean, I can just do the overwrite thing using the empty child view and that will be ok, without proper removing of the other child view. There will be no memory leak or anything?

Comment: is there a way to call deactivate() for the other view so that it can be close manually?